# Finding index of sequence that satisfies given estimation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

How do I find the minimal $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ of sequence $ x_{n}=\frac{4+\sqrt{3n}}{3+\sqrt{3n}} $?
Such that the estimation  $ |x_{n}-1|<\frac{1}{10}, n\geqslant N $ holds? My idea was to find the $\min x_{n} $ and its index would be the solution but the [-1] part tells me, that it would be the correct way since it changes the estimation.

Comment: **Hint :** $$x_n - 1 = \frac{1}{3+\sqrt{3n}}$$
Can you proceed from here ?

Comment: yes, I found desired N to be 17 and turned out it was correct. Thank you for your help!